# Exception when using ajax event on custom selectOneRadio

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use the selectOneRadio with custom layout as shown in the last example here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneRadio.jsf

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="customRadio" layout="custom"
                  value="#{myBB.queryType}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="A"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="B"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="C"/>
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="queryOptions"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
<p:panelGrid columns="3" id="queryOptions">
    <p:radioButton id="option1" for="customRadio" itemIndex="0"/>
    <p:radioButton id="option2" for="customRadio" itemIndex="1"/>
    <p:radioButton id="option3" for="customRadio" itemIndex="2"/>
    <p:inputText value="#{myBB.queryType}"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

I need custom layout, because there are other components in the `queryOptions` panelGrid which I need to update based on the selected radioButton. The value in the backingbean is correctly updated on click, but I get this strange exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.radiobutton.RadioButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(RadioButtonRenderer.java:48)
at org.primefaces.component.radiobutton.RadioButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(RadioButtonRenderer.java:38)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeDynamicBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:92)
at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:60)
at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:559)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1729)
```

What could be causing it?

I'm using Primefaces 4.0 and Mojarra 2.2.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I can see that you are putting the `p:radioButton` inside the ajax update panelGrid.

This way you are updating the `p:radioButton` without updating the customeRadio ('owner').

You can solve this by two ways:

*First:* update also the p:selectOneRadio related to the radioButtons

```
<p:ajax process="@this" update="queryOptions @this"/>
```

***OR***

*Second:* put the radioButtons outside the updated container.

```
<p:radioButton id="option1" for="customRadio" itemIndex="0"/>
<p:radioButton id="option2" for="customRadio" itemIndex="1"/>
<p:radioButton id="option3" for="customRadio" itemIndex="2"/>
<p:panelGrid columns="3" id="queryOptions">

</p:panelGrid>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I don't get the exception any more when I update the common parent. But I've got another problem with this. The values in the ```queryOptions``` panel are not updated(I've edited the post and the inputText only changes the value on page refresh). Any idea?

Comment: Of course they won't be updated, since the process of the ajax is @this, you might need to process also the radioButtons... for example:
`<p:ajax process="@this queryOptions" update="queryOptions @this"/>`.
because basically the radioButtons and the inputtext are rendered in the grid, and are not being processed, so the value is not updated !

Comment: Well... this component confused me a bit. Thanks! One last question. When I have ```<p:ajax process="@this queryOptions" update="queryOptions @this"/>``` the update works, but I can only select item once. Then I have to refresh to make another selection. No exceptions. Maybe it would also be a no-brainer for you :)

Comment: in fact it's pretty much strange behavior.
as I have tested, some how the script of the component (in order to create the PrimeFaces widget) is not called after the update.
So in this case I have to put panelGroup surrounding the selectOneRadio and the panelGrid .. then in the update I update the panelGroup... this way the script would be called "strangely"

Comment: It is strange. It only works when I enclose it in common panel(queryPanel) and define the ajax event like this: ```<p:ajax process="queryOptions @this" update="queryPanel"/>```. Thanks a lot. I wish I could give you more points :)