# Primefaces selectOneRadio(RadioButton) update panelGrid within Dialog

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

i m trying to update a `panelgrid` form `selectOneRadio` within a dialog.
Every time i chose on of the two options the whole `panelGrid` collapse and a NPE is thorw without any details.

My Sourcecode:

```
<h:form id="form_tmpVst">
        <p:dialog id="dialog_tmpVst" header="Temporäre Verkaufsstelle" widgetVar="dialog_tmpVst" modal="true" resizable="false" showEffect="clip">

            <p:selectOneRadio id="radio_placeOnMap" value="#{mapBean.placedByAddress}" layout="custom">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Karte" itemValue="#{false}" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Adresse" itemValue="#{true}" />
                <p:ajax update="panel_tmpVst" />
                <!-- <p:ajax @process="@this" update="@this panelTempVst" /> -->
            </p:selectOneRadio>

            <p:panelGrid id="panel_tmpVst">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column colspan="2">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Platzierung: " />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:radioButton id="radio_tmpVstPlaceByAddress" for="radio_placeOnMap" itemIndex="0" />
                        <p:outputLabel value="Karte" for="radio_tmpVstPlaceByAddress" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:radioButton id="radio_tmpVstPlaceByMap" for="radio_placeOnMap" itemIndex="1" />
                        <p:outputLabel value="Adresse" for="radio_tmpVstPlaceByMap" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputTextarea id="txtarea_address" rows="5" cols="30" counter="txtarea_counter" maxlength="200" counterTemplate="{0} Zeichen übrig."
                            autoResize="false" value="test data __öäüöäöüöäö" required="#{mapBean.placedByAddress}" disabled=" #{!mapBean.placedByAddress}"
                            style="resize: none;" />
                        <br />
                        <h:outputText id="txtarea_counter" style="font-size: .5em;" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Name:" for="txt_tmpname" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText id="txt_tmpname" value="#{mapBean.tmpVstName}" required="true" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="BST:" for="txt_bsttmp" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText id="txt_bsttmp" value="#{mapBean.tmpDistrict}" required="true" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="VST:" for="txt_vsttmp" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputText id="txt_vsttmp" value="#{mapBean.tmpVstNumber}" required="true" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <p:commandButton value="Hinzufügen" id="btn_addTmpVst" action="#{mapBean.addTempVst()}" type="submit" ajax="true"
                update=":dataTableForm:markerListDataTable, :mapForm:map, :growl" oncomplete="PF('dialog_tmpVst').hide();" />
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

Before: 
[image]

After radio-button klick:

[image]

Many Thanks in advence

Comment: which browsers you are using?

Comment: Tested in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Probably best to have the `<h:form/>` *inside* the `<p:dialog/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, basiclly you're updating the `h:panelGrid` which contains the `p:radioButton`s without a notice to the owner (`p:selectOneRadio`).

To solve this update the `p:selectOneRadio` alongside the `h:panelGrid`, that way the rendering would work as expected:

```
<p:ajax update="panel_tmpVst radio_placeOnMap" />
```

Comment: doesn't work, the radiobutton can only switched once and the `<p:inputTextarea id="txtarea_address" ... disabled="#!mapBean.placedByAddress}" />`  isn't disabled after switching

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22017066/exception-when-using-ajax-event-on-custom-selectoneradio/22017603#22017603).. where do you get the NPE ?

Comment: As I can see that you have commented a p:ajax, which seems find to me ? I mean the process would process that component then the update would be fine ? it's not working, are you getting any error from that line ?

Comment: `<p:ajax update="panel_tmpVst" />` -> java.lang.NullPointerException  (no details/stacktrace logged by glassfish)-> form collapse 

`<p:ajax update=":form_tmpVst:panel_tmpVst @this" />` -> can only switch once -> textarea is still enabled -> no error

Comment: Placing the <h:form/> inside the <p:dialog/> and update only the Form worked